# Two exclusive conditions along with one or condition for two values in switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

Is there a way to do

```
switch (expr) {
case space or tab:
print 'one of em + '
case space:
print 'space'
case tab:
print 'tab'
}
```

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| tab | one of em + tab |
| space | one of em + space |

If not, what are the alternatives? I know I could use `if else` but since I'm only using one expression as input, `switch` seems more appropriate

Comment: From your sample pseudo-code, it is not clear whether you are asking to have the case “space” and the case “tab” both send control to the same place inside the `switch` or whether you asking to have the case “space” send control to two different places inside the `switch`, and to have the case “tab” send control to two places. The former is easy. The latter is not a feature of the C standard. Edit your post to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: [Edit] and improve your pseudo code and add examples of input with expected output for all (2 or 3?) cases of expr.

Comment: I mean the latter. I have code (say C1) that must be executed when either space or tab is encountered and code that must be executed when space is encountered (say C2) and C3 for when tab is encountered

Comment: @SeetheMoar please [edit] the question and put all clarifications _there_

Comment: I have edited the question with a table for the inputs and expected outputs. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @SeetheMoar yes, much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with a `switch`.

But with `if` it's really simple and readable:

```
if (expr == space || expr == tab)
  print 'one of em + '
if (expr == space)
  print 'space'
else if (expr == tab)
  print 'tab'
```

or better:

```
if (expr == space || expr == tab)
{
  print 'one of em + '
  if (expr == space)
    print 'space'
  else if (expr == tab)
    print 'tab'
}
```

or even better:

```
if (expr == space || expr == tab)
{
  print 'one of em + '
  if (expr == space)
    print 'space'
  else             // if (expr == tab) is not needed because
    print 'tab'    //  tab is the only possible outcome here.
}
```

All code above is pseudo code.